# GMail wildcard searching

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-search

I am getting a lot of spam e-mail that would be easy to filter if I could figure out if GMail supports wildcards in searching and filtering.  Alot of spam is addressed or CCd the same kind of e-mail address, for example:

```
steve##@hotmail.com
```

It's only the ## part that is changing.

But I can't seem to find a wilcard that works for this.  I tried:

```
steve*@hotmail.com
steve?@hotmail.com
steve??@hotmail.com
```

They don't work.

What will work?  Does regular expression work?

Comment: No, in HTML Gmail **wildcards are not supported** and **regex  is not supported**. You would need to use Google Apps Script to do those kinds of searches.